# Train-test split strategies in sensor time series

Tags: time-series, training, multiclass-classification, activity-recognition

i'd like to train a supervised machine learning algorithm on my sensor data (Accelerometer XYZ). I've already segmented the data with a sliding window approach (1s window_size, 50% overlap) and calculated some features (like IQR, std, etc.) per window.

I'm not really sure, which train-test strategy should be applied. Because my data is slightly skewed in class distribution, I'm tempted to use a stratified train-test, but since the sensor data can be considered as time series, this might be not the best approach. Could someone explain the best train-test strategy and provide maybe resources regarding that topic to me, please? (Research papers are also not consistent on that topic.)

Thanks in advance!!